# error: passing ‘constas ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a singleton class:

```
class ObjectModel {
public:
    virtual ~ObjectModel();
    static ObjectModel& Get();

    const AttributeStruct operator [] (const std::string &symbol_path) const {
        auto path = split(symbol_path, '.');

        if (path.size() != 2) {
            throw std::runtime_error(Formatter() << "Path '" 
               << symbol_path << "' has a wrong format.");
        }

        const CipAttributeStruct attr = this->dic[path[0]][path[1]];
        if (attr.data == nullptr) {
            throw std::runtime_error(Formatter() << "Attribute '" 
               << symbol_path << "' isn't found.");
        }

        return attr;
    }
private:
    ObjectModel();
    ObjectModel( const ObjectModel& );
    ObjectModel& operator=( ObjectModel& );

    std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, CipAttributeStruct> > dic = {};
};
```

Usage:

```
void main() {
    auto &m = ObjectModel::Get();

    std::cout << *static_cast<uint32_t*>(m["Object1.Attribute"].data);
}
```

I can't compile this code due to an error:

> error: passing ‘const std::map, std::map, lynx::cip::CipAttributeStruct> >’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
>     const CipAttributeStruct attr = this->dic[path[0]][path[1]];

I see lots questions of this kind here, but none of them helps me. I know I can remove **const** qualifier to avoid the problem. But I wonder if there is another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of couple of ways you can solve your problem.

1. Use [`std::map::at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at). If you use `std::map::at()`, you have to add code to catch exceptions. If there isn't an item corresponding to the key, `std::map::at()` will throw an exception.

   ```
   const CipAttributeStruct attr = nullptr;
   try
   {
      attr = this->dic.at(path[0]).at(path[1]);
   }
   catch (...)
   {
      // Deal with missing key
   }
   ```
2. Use [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) and deal with non-existing keys.

   ```
   auto it1 = this->dic.find(path[0]);
   if ( it1 == this->dic.end() )
   {
      // Deal with missing key
   }

   auto it2 = (*it1).find(path[1]);
   if ( it2 == (*it1).end() )
   {
      // Deal with missing key
   }

   const CipAttributeStruct attr = it2->second;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Because `operator[]` is potentially destructive it's not a `const` operation. If you only want to *observe* the contents of the map, use `at`:

```
const CipAttributeStruct attr = this->dic.at(path[0]).at(path[1]);
```